# Clean vector with elements occurring in series

Tags: r

Presented with a vector like below,

```
vec01 <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1,
           2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2,
           1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1,
           2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3,
           1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1)
```

Problem1: how to remove the anomalies highlighted below:

```
vec01 <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1,
           2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, *2*, *2*,
           1, 2, *2*, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1,
           2, 1, 2, 3, 4, *2*, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3,
           1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1)
```

Definition of anomaly: the element need to be part of the series 1,2,....  the ones marked in bold above

Problem2: how to identify the groups of series after removing the anomalies, each sequence belonging to one group i.e., a output like

```
result <- structure(list(vec = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L,
                                 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L),
                         group = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L,
                                   8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L,
                                   11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L)),
                         .Names = c("vec", "group"),
                         row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: what's marked in bold? your "definition" needs a bit more explanation. I don't find it clear. And what's 'groups of series' in problem 2??

Comment: @Arun I think the OP try to find group by regular `sequence` : 123 is good sequence  but 122 is not a regular sequence..

Comment: yes @agstudy..thats what i mean

Comment: @agstudy, this question is very poorly framed, wouldn't you agree? flagged as "very low quality".

Comment: actually @agstudy got the question and approach to the answer correct,,,and now i don't see his answer...

Comment: @srbhgaur, if your question had enough clarity, then there wouldn't much need for that many exchanges in comments. you'll just have to explain better what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem, here is another solution. It looks where the values are incrementing and builds the corresponding ideal (no anomalies) sequence `vec02`. Then it is just a matter of comparing `vec01` and `vec02`.

```
is.incr <- c(FALSE, diff(vec01) == 1)
vec02   <- rep(1, length(vec01)) + sequence(rle(is.incr)$lengths) * is.incr
vec     <- vec01[vec01 == vec02]
result  <- data.frame(vec = vec, group = cumsum(vec == 1))
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is for problem 2 (and problem 1 if you remove all TRUE at the end)

```
library(data.table)  #load data.table because syntax is nice (matter of pers taste)
DT = data.table(vec01)
DT[,counter:=ifelse(vec01==1,1,0)]  #identify each sequence starting with one
DT[,counter:=cumsum(counter)]  #trick to give a diff ID to each seq so we can use by
DT[,flag:=is.unsorted(vec01),by=counter]  #check sorting for each sequence
```

EDIT: replace `is.unsorted` by `f(vec01)` with `f = function(x){!(x==Reduce(max,x,accumulate=T))}`

Comment: one prob...i am getting anomaly=TRUE for whole group...12322 all elements are marked TRUE...123 need be false...

Comment: ok then create a function say `f` that take a UNIQUE sequence like 12322 and return the appropriate TTTFF and replace `is.unsorted` by this function say `f`. Can you do that ?

Comment: Some is downvoting all answers :)

Comment: @Arun: Lol exactly what I was thinking

Comment: @Ali, we know that, I am waiting for the OP to solve the last bit

Comment: Still the code does not work for `vec01 <- c(1,2,3,3,3,3,1)`.

Comment: fro me 1 start a new sequence, what the OP want is not clear. As long as we do not have a clear question it will be speculations

Comment: 1 starts a new sequence, and the sequence is expanded while every item is one unit greater than previous, items between two consecutive sequences should be cleared

Answer (score 2):

To clean sequence (question 1):

```
m <- vec01[1]==1
for (i in seq(2,length(vec01))) 
    m[i] <- vec01[i]==1 || vec01[i]==vec01[i-1]+1 && m[i-1]
vec01 <- vec01[m]
```

Now to make your desired structure (Thanks @statquant for `cumsum()` idea):

```
data.frame(vec=vec01, group=cumsum(c(1,diff(vec01)!=1)))
```

Comment: which question is this answer to?

Comment: data.table is blazing fast and update by reference, you are unlinkely to find quickest alternatives unless you code in C/C++ via Rcpp